# graficar multiples funciones guardadas en matriz

Tags: python, sympy

actualmente me encuentro trabajando en una tarea donde debo hacer que se resuelvan las funciones que voy ingresando a sympy y que este las grafiques, mi problema viene a que las funciones las estoy guardando en un array para mostrarlas todas juntas, y no sé cómo hacer que sympy tome esos valores para graficar.

Probé con ciclo for, pero eso crea una a una las graficas, buscando entendí que la forma de poder graficar varias es declararlo todo en una, por ejemplo:

```
plot(y_despejado,y2_despejado)
```

Sin embargo, yo poseo un array 3 o más funciones qué deseo graficar.

Dejo el código con el que estoy haciendo las pruebas, ya que es más simplificado y es donde está mi problema (perdón si está algo desordenado, pero es para testear más que tora cosa) agradezco su ayuda.

```
from sympy import *
import sympy
# Definimos las variables x e y
x, y = sympy.symbols('x y')

# Definimos la ecuación
ecuacion = sympy.Eq(3*x + 2*y, 18)
ecuacion2 = sympy.Eq(5*x + 6*y, 18)

# Despejamos y
y_despejado = sympy.solve(ecuacion, y)[0]
y2_despejado = sympy.solve(ecuacion2, y)[0]

Lista = []
Lista.append(y_despejado)
Lista.append(y2_despejado)
# Imprimimos el resultado
print("La ecuación despejada es y =", y_despejado)

x,y=symbols('x y')
plot(y_despejado,y2_despejado)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para graficar varias funciones al mismo tiempo utilizando SymPy, puedes utilizar la función plot con los nombres de las funciones en una lista. En tu caso, podrías hacer algo así:

```
from sympy import *

# Definimos las variables x e y
x, y = symbols('x y')

# Definimos las ecuaciones
ecuacion1 = Eq(3*x + 2*y, 18)
ecuacion2 = Eq(5*x + 6*y, 18)

# Despejamos y
y_despejado1 = solve(ecuacion1, y)[0]
y_despejado2 = solve(ecuacion2, y)[0]

# Creamos la lista de funciones a graficar
funciones = [y_despejado1, y_despejado2]

# Graficamos todas las funciones juntas
plot(*funciones, (x, -10, 10))
```

En este ejemplo, `funciones` es una lista con las dos funciones despejadas que deseas graficar. Luego, al pasar el argumento `*funciones` en la función plot, le indicas a SymPy que tome cada elemento de la lista como una función distinta para graficar. Por último, también se especifica el rango de valores de `x` que se deben graficar.

Con este enfoque, puedes agregar más funciones a la lista funciones y se graficarán todas juntas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, maestro, me sirvo de maravilla